# How did I meet these city states?

Tags: civilization-5

How did I meet these city states?

As you can see in they are deep in the fog.
[image]

The minimap showing the view angle. There are two dots in there if you look hard enough.

[image]

The last event for Kuala Lumpar.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least three ways this can happen:

1. Another city-state asked you to destroy them
2. That city-state declared war on you (because you went to war with their ally)
3. You encountered a unit of the city state

It looks like Hanoi at least you are at war with.

Comment: a third way is you might have met a ship from that city state (can't remember if this reveals the city on the map, though)

Comment: Of course! Please add that an an answer so I can vote it up.

Comment: @Valamas updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you know a citystate that wants you to wipe that unmet citystate out, you get to meet them for free.

Answer (score 1):

As HorusKol states. I did met another city state because their ship visited me.